# Why has the structure pointer have the wrong values

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

So I started looking into Datastructures in C and wanted to code a Singly Linked List.

this is a small piece of it:

```
struct nodes {
    int val;
    struct nodes *next;
};

void insert(struct nodes *list, int val) {
    struct nodes *tmp = (struct nodes*) malloc(sizeof(struct nodes));
    tmp->val = val;
    tmp->next = list;
    list = tmp;
}

int main() {
    struct nodes *test;
    insert(test, 5);
    insert(test, 10);

    printf("test %d\n", test->next->val);
}
```

Here I get totally wrong output. When I try writing a function where I don't have to pass in the structure pointer, it works like expected.

OUTPUT:

```
test 90053
```

P.S I'm still starting with C so don't judge too hard :D

Comment: Tip: Call your individual structures `node`. Here `nodes` implies that it's an array or a collection of them, but it's not. It's just one node that happens to link to another.

Comment: OT: regarding; `struct nodes *tmp = (struct nodes*) malloc(sizeof(struct nodes));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone)  Suggest removing that cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed");` to output both the error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding; `struct nodes *test;`  this leaves `test` pointing to some unknown memory address.  Strongly suggest: `struct nodes *test = NULL;'

Comment: regarding: `insert(test, 5);` and `insert(test, 10);`  The `insert()` function needs to be able to change where `test` points.  Therefore, the function: `insert()` needs to be passed the address of `test`, so `insert()` can change where `test` points.  Suggest:  `insert( &test, 5);` and `insert( &test, 10);`  Notice the `&` so the address of `test` is passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go on this way:

```
    struct nodes {
    int val;
    struct nodes* next;
};

nodes* insert(struct nodes* list, int val) {
    struct nodes* tmp = (struct nodes*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodes));
    tmp->val = val;
    tmp->next = list;
    return tmp;
}
```

When experimenting with structures like that the 1st function you write --- I believe --- is list() not insert().

In every function that can change the start address of the list you must **return the address** or it would be lost. And since you only insert at the beginning you lost everything, as the start address is always changed..
In general do not use `void`. At a minimum is a waste, often an error. Return something, like a completion status. See an implementation of `list()` that returns... the `size`

```
int         list(struct nodes* list)
{
    struct nodes* p = list;
    int N = 0;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("#%d  %d\n", N, p->val);
        p = p->next; N += 1;
    };
    printf("\n");
    return N;
}
```

#### and a version of main() using the 2 functions

```
int main() {
    struct nodes* test = NULL;
    int n = 0;
    for(n = 800; n>0; n-= 100) test = insert(test, n);
    n = list(test);
    printf("At the end list() returned %d\n", n);
}
```

this way you have more info since the beginning.

```
#0  100
#1  200
#2  300
#3  400
#4  500
#5  600
#6  700
#7  800

At the end list() returned 8
```

#### a test program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct no
{
    void*       item;
    struct no*  next;
    struct no*  prev;
};  // no
typedef struct no Node;

typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    unsigned  size;
    unsigned  limit;
    Node* start;
    Node* end;
}   List;

struct nodes {
    int val;
    struct nodes* next;
};

struct nodes*   insert(struct nodes*, int);
int             list(struct nodes* L);

int main() {
    struct nodes* test = NULL;
    int n = 0;
    for(n = 800; n>0; n-= 100) test = insert(test, n);
    n = list(test);
    printf("At the end list() returned %d\n", n);
}

struct nodes*   insert(struct nodes* list, int val) {
    struct nodes* tmp = (struct nodes*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodes));
    tmp->val = val;
    tmp->next = list;
    return tmp;
}

int         list(struct nodes* list)
{
    struct nodes* p = list;
    int N = 0;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("#%d  %d\n", N, p->val);
        p = p->next; N += 1;
    };
    printf("\n");
    return N;
}
```

As pointed in the comments, note that a list is not a `node`. A list if a collection of nodes, and the nodes have a data payload. If the payload is a `(void*)` then you have a really abstract data structure since it can load anything, from a single `char` to a `100-fields structure`.

Think about the way you wrote it and the case you have 5 lists in your program: a mess it will turn into very fast. And compare with something like the code below

#### a linked list structure

```
struct no
{
    void*       item;
    struct no*  next;
    struct no*  prev;
};  // no
typedef struct no Node;

typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    unsigned  size;
    unsigned  limit;
    Node* start;
    Node* end;
}   List;
```

Note that as you put more info into the `List` things get easier: you have always a size, a limit, pointers to start and end, and so on

Comment: Wow thanks. This is a really good explanation. And a lot of tips for good practice, thanks. Why is it generally better to return the tmp an an insert?

Comment: And one quick question:
Why doesn't it also work with `list = tmp;`. I mean isn't list a reference to the structure it is pointing to and I am setting the new pointer to the `tmp` structure. Or is tmp structure also destroyed on function end even though it is initialized with `malloc()`?

Comment: like I said, you have 2 options doing this way: (a) to pass the address of the pointer to the functions or (b) to return it from the functions. (a) uses `List**` head.. (b) just returns `List*`. Maybe just me but I find it more clear to return the address, like in `head = delete_list(head);` This shows the pointer being invalidated. 
But if you noticed the alternative structures in the program I posted I think you see that to encapsulate the `List` metadata and pass just its address makes for an easier way: inside `List` you have all about it

Comment: As `list = tmp` you are right: `list` is local, `tmp` is local. Everything is local. (Consider using a convention like in the program I posted and using `typedef` to name the structs as types. It is a pain to type `struct` everywhere although is makes things clear). Even if you use `struct list** thing` it is local. `thing` is local. It works just because `*thing` is the same address the caller sent. It is really important to understand this in C.

Comment: the OP ask about a singly linked list and did not ask about tracking both ends of the list and did not ask about tracking the number of entries in the list,  Therefore, this is NOT a good answer

Comment: @user3629249 this is called an example and you can find it is pointless to see that there are other ways and reasons to do it in any other way. May be you know what is inertia also. Others can see it as useful as it points to advantages of writing the code in another way. This is a public forum anyway

Answer (score 3):

You're altering a local variable so there's no effect on the caller. What you might mean is to use a pointer to a pointer so that can be changed:

```
int main() {
    struct nodes *test = NULL; // Don't forget to initialize
    insert(&test, 5);
    insert(&test, 10);

    printf("test %d\n", test->next->val);
}
```

Where your function now looks like:

```
void insert(struct nodes **list, int val) {
    struct nodes *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct nodes)); // No need to cast malloc() in C
    tmp->val = val;
    tmp->next = *list;
    *list = tmp;
}
```

Since `list` is de-referenced (`*list`) it actually alters the original value (that is pointed to) meaning your list head changes.

In your original code you never initialized `list`, it's just some random garbage value, and because `insert` can never change it, it stays as junk data. Accessing any data through that is undefined behaviour so you'll get junk data or a crash.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer :D
Yeah initializing would be good idea.

Comment: But isn't the `*test` already a pointer? Didn't I set the address with `list->tmp`?

Comment: You set the `next` pointer. There is no `list->tmp`. A pointer to a pointer is a C way of passing in a "mutable pointer".

Comment: In your original code `list = tmp` changes the *local variable only*, and that local variable only exists within the scope of that function. In other words, `list` is copied in by value, and any direct changes to that value are temporary. `*list` does not change list, it changes the *target of the pointer* so it's completely different.

Comment: If you want to see how this works in practice it's extremely educational to step through this code in a debugger line by line and see how your variables change or don't change. You'll see that `list` does change in your code, but `test` in the calling function is unaltered because `list` is a copy.

Comment: I did that now. But I still dont quite understand it. When I use a pointer, no matzer what it is, it isn't a copy, The address points to the actual value in the memory.

Comment: Sorry for these questions but I feel really stupid rn

Comment: I understand it like an array when you need to pass `int *arr` into a function, the array you want to pass, is already a pointer. So when you use `arr` in the function it is not the copy, but the original value. So isn't it here the same thing but with structures. Shouldnt a pointer to a Structure be enough to change the members of the Structure?    I really just want to understand it.

Comment: When you *de-reference* it changes happen, but not unless. That is `arr[1] = 9` assigns *through* the `arr` pointer, but it importantly does not change what `arr` is, it's still a pointer to the same memory address. `arr = &other[0]` does change it locally but not in the parent.

Comment: Think of this as changing a reference to a reference, as in you want to change the original reference.